# Anyway to bind keyboard to dash (Debian Almquist Shell)?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, dash, interactive, vi-mode

Specifically Up/Down for history navigation.

## What I already know

I understand [`dash`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian_Almquist_shell#Dash) is a minimalistic, no bloat, (somewhat) strict POSIX shell.

I understand the philosophy behind it, and the reason features, that have become basic in other interactive shells, are not present in `dash`.

I've looked into the following resources:

- [man](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/dash.1.html) page
- [Arch Linux Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Dash) page

As well as a bunch of other pages and answers specific about history in `dash`.

From my reading, I gather *there is* a history mechanism, as well as a `vi` mode.
However I can't find how to map the `<ESCAPE>` key, or the `[UP]`/`[DOWN]` arrow keys (or any key) to any meaningful action.

No `bind` or `bindkey` builtin commands either.

My goal - make dash minimally usable as an interactive shell for debugging purposes.

## Questions

- Is there a default mapping?
- Is there a way to manipulate the keyboard mapping in dash?
- Is there another source of information that can shed some light on interactive usability of dash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into this problem on macOS and ended up finding that the simplest option was to use `rlwrap` (https://github.com/hanslub42/rlwrap).

In my particular case, in iTerm, I set up a profile for `dash` with the following command to execute it whenever I want to use the `dash` shell (`-l` is for login mode; `-E` is for emacs command line editor vs `-V` for vi):

```
/opt/homebrew/bin/rlwrap /bin/dash -l -E
```

Comment: Using your answer, I've found [another question](https://askubuntu.com/q/86905/720005) discussing this type of tools.

This is awesome - thank you for setting me on the right path.